# Odd custom objects behavior (duplicates one object, removes another) in NSMutableArray after it's restored from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm quite new to Objective-C (and coding in general) and I'm developing an iOS project to get familiar with persistent storage of custom objects.

Everything went well during the first phase of development (also thanks to many answers I found here on StackOverflow) 'til a couple of days ago, when I hit an odd behavior I'm not able to understand nor solve. I'll try to describe the app and explain the problem I'm having at best of my ability (english is not my main language, sorry).

The structure of the app already has:

- A custom class for the weight objects (each object has a few properties: `NSDate`, int for kilograms, int for grams, a float for kilograms, etc...);
- A MainViewController, containing a UIPickerView with two components (kilos and grams), a "save selected weight" button that add the current weight object (actually, an exact copy of it - I implemented the NSCoping protocol) to a `NSMutableArray` inserting it at index 0, a "history" button that triggers a segue to a FlipSideViewController and a couple of label showing the date of the last recorded weight and its value;
- A `FlipSideViewController` that contains a TableView in which I load the values of the NSMutableArray.
- There's also a SettingsViewController, but it doesn't do anything yet and it's not relevant for this issue (I'm mentioning it just because there are some reference to it the code I include later).

**I implemented data persistence through `NSUserDefaults` and adding the `NSCoding` methods (initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder) in my custom weight class: I encode and decode the array containing the custom weight objects (`NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj`) since, if I get that correctly, NSUserDefaults doesn't allow to store custom objects that aren't encoded in `NSData`.**

The basic interactions already work:

- If I start clean, without restoring previously stored data, I can create many new weight objects, which are added to the NSMutableArray and showed in the TableView of the FlipSideViewController.
- Everything seems fine (but it's not, as I will explain later) even if I restore the previously recorded data: the labels in the `MainViewController` show the values of the last object previously recorded, the row of the PickerView match the last selected values, the TableView in the `FlipSideViewController` shows the restored values of the array...

But there's a but: when I restore previous data (point 2 above), even if everything looks correct, as I hit the "save button" to add a new record the values in the array are messed up.

It's maybe easier to explain how they are messed up with an example:

*Let's say that in a first session I save 3 different weight values: first 12,0 kg, then 25,0 kg and last 70,0 kg.
Then the TableView shows 70,0 kg at top, 25,0 kg as the second value and 12,0 as third value; the labels on the MainViewController obviously show 70,0 kg since it's the last value recorded.
Now, if I quit the app and launch it again, after it's loaded everything looks exactly before I quit: the label show 70,0 kg and the TableView has the same 3 values in the same order.*
***The issue starts if I want to add a new value, let's say 100,5 kg, by pressing the save button: after that, the values shown in the TableView change in a way that I don't understand: top to bottom, the values now are 100,5 - 100,5 (yes, it's duplicated instead of showing 70,0), 25,0, 12,0.***

I have no clue of the issue; maybe something happens with the index of the array when it's recreated, but I don't get why and how.

I suppose it's better that I also provide the code for clarity; please excuse if my variable names and methods names are usually in italian (I won't do that again, I realize now that if I have to ask something in english is best that my code also doesn't contain a trace of italian).

I don't know if it's preferred to include all the code; since the behavior looks quite strange to me, I suppose the issues are in something I did somewhere else, so I hope it's okay if I include everything:

**My custom class: Peso.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Peso : NSObject <NSCopying,NSCoding>

@property int pesoChili;
@property int pesoGrammi;
@property float pesoInChiloGrammi;

@property NSDate * dataPesatura;

@property NSString * pesoChilogrammi;
@property NSString * DataPesaturaStringa;

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;

@end
```

**My custom class: Peso.m**

```
#import "Peso.h"

@implementation Peso


-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{

    Peso *copy = [[Peso alloc] init];

    if (copy)
    {
        copy.PesoChili = self.pesoChili;
        copy.pesoGrammi = self.pesoGrammi;
        copy.pesoInChiloGrammi = self.pesoInChiloGrammi;
        copy.dataPesatura = self.dataPesatura;
        copy.pesoChilogrammi = self.pesoChilogrammi;
        copy.DataPesaturaStringa = self.DataPesaturaStringa;
    }

    return copy;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    _pesoChili = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"pesoChili"];
    _pesoGrammi = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"pesoGrammi"];
    _pesoInChiloGrammi = [aDecoder decodeFloatForKey:@"pesoInChiloGrammi"];
    _dataPesatura = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dataPesatura"];
    _pesoChilogrammi = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"pesoChilogrammi"];
    _DataPesaturaStringa = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DataPesaturaStringa"];
    return self;
}


-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{

    [aCoder encodeInt:_pesoChili forKey:@"pesoChili"];
    [aCoder encodeInt:_pesoGrammi forKey:@"pesoGrammi"];
    [aCoder encodeFloat:_pesoInChiloGrammi forKey:@"pesoInChiloGrammi"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_dataPesatura forKey:@"dataPesatura"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_pesoChilogrammi forKey:@"pesoChilogrammi"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_DataPesaturaStringa forKey:@"DataPesaturaStringa"];
}

@end
```

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "Peso.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,SettingsViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#define kPercorso @"percorsoArrayCronologiaPeso30"

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataPesoCorrente;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelPesoCorrente;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottoneRegistraPeso;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bottoneHistory;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *thePicker;

@end

@implementation MainViewController {
    NSMutableArray *cronologiaPeso;
    Peso * pesoRilevato;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}


- (IBAction)salvaPesoCorrente:(id)sender {

    pesoRilevato.pesoChilogrammi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d kg",pesoRilevato.pesoChili,pesoRilevato.pesoGrammi];

    pesoRilevato.dataPesatura = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd yyyy - hh:mm:ss a"];
    pesoRilevato.DataPesaturaStringa = [formatter stringFromDate:pesoRilevato.dataPesatura];

    self.labelPesoCorrente.text = pesoRilevato.pesoChilogrammi;

    self.dataPesoCorrente.text = pesoRilevato.DataPesaturaStringa;

    self.bottoneHistory.hidden = NO;

    [self nuoviValori];

}


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 2;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return 201;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 10;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }

}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
            break;
        default:
            return @"error";
            break;
    }

}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (component == 0) {
        pesoRilevato.pesoChili = row;
    }

    if (component == 1) {
        pesoRilevato.pesoGrammi = row;
    }

    [self combinaChiliEGrammi];

}


-(void)combinaChiliEGrammi{

    pesoRilevato.pesoInChiloGrammi = pesoRilevato.pesoGrammi;

    while (pesoRilevato.pesoInChiloGrammi >= 1) {
        pesoRilevato.pesoInChiloGrammi /= 10;
    }

    pesoRilevato.pesoInChiloGrammi += pesoRilevato.pesoChili;

    self.bottoneRegistraPeso.hidden = NO;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.bottoneRegistraPeso.hidden = YES;
    self.bottoneHistory.hidden = YES;

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation].allKeys containsObject:kPercorso]) {

        cronologiaPeso = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self caricaCronologiaPesoCodificatoConKey:kPercorso]];

        self.bottoneHistory.hidden = NO;
        self.bottoneRegistraPeso.hidden = NO;

        self.labelPesoCorrente.text = [[cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:0]pesoChilogrammi];
        self.dataPesoCorrente.text = [[cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:0]DataPesaturaStringa];

        [self.thePicker selectRow:[[cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:0]pesoChili] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [self.thePicker selectRow:[[cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:0]pesoGrammi] inComponent:1 animated:YES];

        if (!pesoRilevato){
            pesoRilevato = [cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    } else {
        pesoRilevato = [[Peso alloc]init];
        cronologiaPeso = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

}


-(void)nuoviValori{

    [cronologiaPeso insertObject:[pesoRilevato copy] atIndex:0];

    //    [cronologiaPeso insertObject:[pesoRilevato copy] atIndex:pesoRilevato.contatoreOggettiPeso];

    [self salvaArrayCronologiaPesoCodificandolo:cronologiaPeso];

}



-(void)salvaArrayCronologiaPesoCodificandolo:(NSMutableArray*)obj{
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
    [defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:kPercorso];
    [defaults synchronize];
}


-(NSArray*)caricaCronologiaPesoCodificatoConKey:(NSString*)key{
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey: key];
    NSArray* obj = (NSArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
    return obj;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)settingsViewControllerDidFinish:(SettingsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];

        FlipsideViewController * nextViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [nextViewController setCronologiaPeso:cronologiaPeso];


    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showSettings"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }


}

@end
```

** FlipsideViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Peso.h"

@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property NSMutableArray *cronologiaPeso;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

** FlipsideViewController.m**

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideViewController{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.cronologiaPeso.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cella" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Peso * currentPeso = [self.cronologiaPeso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = currentPeso.pesoChilogrammi;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentPeso.DataPesaturaStringa;

    return cell;

}

// NOT YET IMPLEMENTED
//-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    return YES;
//}
//
//
//-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
//        [self.cronologiaPeso removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
////        [defaults synchronize]
//    }
//}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

@end
```

**Please excuse if this question is so long, and maybe not so clear, and if I have included all the code; clearly I'm doing something wrong when saving or restoring the array, but I have no idea how and where... or maybe is the entire pattern I'm following to save and restore data that is wrong, I'm self-taught and I started coding about a month ago, so I'm sure that my logic has serious issues.**

Thanks in advance,

Cesare

Comment: Did you test it on the device or simulator? If you tested it on the device, try to delete the app and rebuild again.

Comment: @Bejibun I tested on the simulator, I don't have an Apple Developer Account yet.

Comment: @Cesare, my advice is to start small.  Make a new project that has no UI, and just your Peso class.  Launch, look in NSUserDefaults for an array of Pesos.  If you don't find one, create one in code and save it to NSUserDefaults.  If you do find one, add a few Pesos to it and resave.  NSLog every step.  If you have a problem, you can come here and post a much smaller question.

Comment: Thank you @danh, your suggestion makes perfects sense: I was worried that I was trying to do too many things at the same time, maybe starting small will help me find the cause of the issue with the array. I'll let you know, thanks again!

Comment: Hi @danh, it's crazy but I'm back to square one also in the simplified project without UI and with less function. I think I better understand what is the issue, but i'm unable to fix it: basically, after (and only after) the Array is restored from NSUSerDefaults, the simple action of adding a new object to the mutable array causes this: the new object is pushed at index 0 as expected, the object at index 1 (that before the new save was at index 0) disappears and is replaced by a copy of the same object at index 0. The same thing happens, in reverse, if I try to add the new object at the end...

Comment: @danh ... of the mutable array: in this case the new object is saved in the last position, the previously last object disappears, and the new object is both in the last and last-1 positions. An example: i have an array with 70 at index 0 and 80 at index 1, if i save a new object (150), then the array has 150 at index 0 and index 1 and 80 at index 2. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong; I also tried to get rid of NSCoping, but passing the object without coping it gives the same result. Any help will be amazing!

Comment: @danh completely out of luck, I just fixed my problem adding a simple parameter... before, when I restored the array from NSUserDefaults I wrote myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.restoredObject.savedArray]; turns out that adding copyItems:YES completely fix the issue I had: I write here (I can't yet answer questions) the solution, if it could help someone else: myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.restoredObject.savedArray copyItems:YES]; Thanks again danh for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Also glad decomposing to a smaller problem made it easier to find and fix the issue.  (It almost always does).  Doing that also has a side effect of making it easier to ask questions here about a very focussed, minimally specified problem.

Comment: Based on your description and without looking at the code it is pretty obvious that you're creating an object, "saving" it, then reusing that same object for a new set of data.  Unless the "saving" operation makes a copy of the data, reusing the object causes both "versions" of the data to be identical.

Comment: @HotLicks It's true that I was reusing the same object, but to avoid issues I inserted a copy in the array and reinitialized the original object every time. I've been able to fix the issue by creating a copy of the objects in the new mutable array when restoring the object from NSUserDefaults (I just added an answer explaining how I solved my issues). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue I had and for which I posted this question (adding an object to a NSMutableArray that was restored from NSUserDefaults caused an odd behavior: the new object was added to the array both at index 0 and at index 1, completely replacing the object that instead should have been at index 1) could easily be fixed.

In my code (that is included in the question above), inside MainViewController.m -> viewDidLoad previously I wrote:

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation].allKeys containsObject:kPercorso]) {

    cronologiaPeso = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self caricaCronologiaPesoCodificatoConKey:kPercorso]];

/...
```

Turns out that adding copyItems:YES to initWithArray: completely solves the issue. The correct code is:

```
//...

cronologiaPeso = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self caricaCronologiaPesoCodificatoConKey:kPercorso] copyItems:YES];

//...
```

I hope this post is useful for someone else...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I correctly understood your question, but one of the problems when working with NSUserDefaults may be because it takes some time to save all data. It basically uses a .plist file internally, so if your data is huge, the updated info may not be available right away, for example if you want to show it on a table view the same millisecond.

My advice is to use some NSMutableDictionary property inside the class you need (or better in a global singleton object, so it is available everywhere), and whenever data is updated, update that dictionary property first, so the view would show the correct data. After that you can save changes in NSUserDefaults as well. Also good practice is to use [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

I hope it helped you somehow :)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Pavlusha. The objects I'm saving are pretty small, so I don't think that speed was the problem. I actually wanted to try to use NSUserDefaults because I'm new to Objective-C and I wanted to see if I were able to use it (I've already used Mutable Dictionary in the last project, I'm trying to take a look at most ways to accomplish tasks). I'm not yet familiar with global singleton objects, now I'm curious and I'll look into it. Thanks again for taking time to help me.